# Powershell Regex with special characters

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to pull info from a log file but can not figure out how to limit the entries to include brackets and two digits in the bracket.

The log file has entries similar to:

```
11/22/22 11:25:26 RandomUselessData12453: 053, Clen 24, Flen 25, Data: [00] Data: [00 01 23 45 03 15]
```

I need to pull only the section of `Data: [00]`

currently using `(?:^|\W)data:(.{5})`

it is pulling

Data: [00]

Data: [00]

Data: [00 0

Data: [00 0

Full Code currently:

```
$LogRegexe = '(?:^|\W)data:(.{5})'
$LogLocation = get-content "C:\blah\log.log" -Tail 80

$LogLocation | 
select-string $LogRegexe |
foreach-object { $_.Matches.Value } |
set-content "C:\blah\log.log"
```

Comment: What is the exact output you're expecting? Only a single string `Data: [00]`? Or just the `00` part?

Comment: I am needing all entries of Data: [00]  there may be different 2 digit combinations in the that set, however there is another set in the log with the same name but contains a different set of returns (i.e. [00 01 34 56 32 12] which is throwing off my current approach

Comment: 2 numbers in brackets?  `\[\d\d]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
\bdata:\s*\[(\d{2})]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bbeekh/1). *Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (much better than `(?:^|\W)`)
- `data:` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `(\d{2})` - Group 1: two digits
- `]` - a `]` char.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for just `Data: [00]`, you can limit it to search for numbers in brackets with just 2 digits: `'Data: \[\d{2}\]'` :

```
Select-String -Path "C:\blah\log.log" -Pattern 'Data: \[\d{2}\]'| 
    ForEach-Object -Process {
        $_.Matches.Value
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Data: [00]
Data: [12]
```

Comment: unfortunately this still returns the longer data set with the same name but different contents.  I am needing specifically entries within the [ ] brackets and only 2 digits

Comment: @BCon995, then can you post what you're using to get that value? i.e., `-match`, `Select-String`, etc.. Can you include an actual (*sanitized*) output of your log so we can work with. Please update your post for the output you're after as well. This skips the guessing on both sides.

Comment: Updated with full code to original post, I appreciate you taking the time to look at this with me.

Comment: @BCon995, does this mean that there may be multiple `Data: [00]`,`Data: [24]`, etc., throughout the log? And you just want all those entries?

Comment: yes sir, specifically entries [01] [02] [03] or [04]